# What is the difference between {{- range .Values.xxx }} and {{ range .Values.xxx }} in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I can both use

```
{{- range .Values.xxx }}
```

and

```
{{ range .Values.xxx }}
```

in my Helm, and the result is the same. Are they totally the same thing？

Also, is the hyphen necessary？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyphen removes any whitespace adjacent to the template construct.  Often this isn't strictly necessary but it makes the rendered output more readable.  Since YAML is whitespace-sensitive sometimes it is required.

Basic example:

```yaml
environment:
{{ range .Values.xxx }}
  - { name: {{ . }}, value: "test" }
{{ end }}
```

Renders to:

```yaml
environment:

  - { name: a, value: "test" }

  - { name: b, value: "test" }
```

On the `range` line, after the `}}` and before the `-`, there is a newline and two spaces; these are required for it to be valid YAML.  Before both of the `{{` there is an additional newline and this isn't required, so you can use `{{-` to suppress it.

```yaml
environment:
{{- range .Values.xxx }}
  - { name: {{ . }}, value: "test" }
{{- end }}
```

```yaml
environment:
  - { name: a, value: "test" }
  - { name: b, value: "test" }
```

This is also useful with functions like `nindent` that include their own newlines.

```yaml
items: {{- .Values.xxx | toYaml | nindent 2 }}
```

```yaml
items:
  - a
  - b
```

`toYaml` converts the list `[a, b]` to the YAML string `- a\n- b`; `nindent 2` adds an initial newline, and two spaces at the start of each line `\n  - a\n  - b`; and then the `-` removes the extra space before the newline that's being emitted.

You can put the `-` inside the closing `}}` too, with the same effect, but that tends to eat the next line's indentation, so it tends to be a little less useful.

(Remember that `helm template` will render a chart to stdout without sending it off to the Kubernetes API server, so you can see what these things expand to.)